# Why does the T-1000 want to keep the photo of John Connor?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

When the T-1000 goes to Todd and Janelle Voight's home, **why does he ask to keep the photo of John?**

Presumably he can remember the photo in perfect detail?

Comment: Aah you mean Todd and Vasquez. Jenette Goldstein is a supremely undercredited actress. I can never spot her in a movie. Aside that, he obviously wants the photo so he can collect a legendary autograph

Comment: “Have you seen this boy?”

Answer (score 65):

It's useful for showing other people the photo and saying "Have you seen this kid?"

This is exactly what happens at the Arcade where they first meet.

Comment: might have freaked people out if he projected a digital picture out of his eyes instead.

Comment: The T-1000 is also pretending to be a cop, and asking to keep the photo is a cop thing to do

Comment: mcgyver5: Might be freakier if it actually formed into John Connor and asked if any kid had seen someone who had looked similar. Then again, i was not that advanced to be able to photocopy something and take the form. It had to have the real John Connor step on it before it could begin to do that!

Answer (score 16):

The T-1000 is using the photo as a tool to help him search for John, showing it to passers-by in the hopes that one of them will recognise him. This works remarkably well.

> EXT. 7-ELEVEN STORE - DAY
>
> Officer X has stopped two young girls in front of a 7-Eleven.  He is
> leaning out the cruiser window and **showing them the picture of John.**
>
> The first girl nods.
>
> **FIRST GIRL:** *Yeah, he was here about fifteen minutes ago.  I think he said he was going to the Galleria.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Terminator 2: Screenplay](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-2-Judgement-Day.html)</sup></sub>

and from the film's official novelisation

> *He [the T-1000] approached a few kids near Perry’s Pizza on the second floor, then
> showed them the photograph. They could only shrug. He glanced over at
> a security guard who was eyeing him curiously. **Austin considered the
> possible alternatives and a second later walked up to the man and
> showed him the photo, asking him to look out for the boy.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Terminator 2: Judgement Day - Official Novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(Frakes_novel))</sup></sub>

---

Comment: But if he can morph himself into any object, can't he make the photo as part of his hand?

Comment: @papirtiger Because that definitely wouldn't arouse suspicion

Comment: He could just make it look like he was pulling it out of his pocket. He can obviously create clothing, so a piece of paper with an image on it must be possible.

Comment: He could make it look like he was pulling it out of his pocket, but what would be the point? He makes his own clothes instead of taking them from the person he's replacing because being able to change clothes at a moment's notice and not having them show bullet holes helps him blend in. There's no strategic advantage to mimicking the photo. And he doesn't have to devote part of his body to creating it by just keeping the picture.

Comment: Also, +1 for Wayne's World.

Comment: @Alarion - I didn't think anyone would spot it :-)

Comment: Out of cannon, because if he didn't take the picture they'd have to spend a lot of money for expensive CGI to show him morphing it out of his hand at least once to fight of the nit picking fans.  In cannon, because even if T1000 could fake it that way, a physical picture can be handed to a potential witness to look at more closely.  Faking and not being able to as a result would be weird in an attract unwanted attention sort of way.

Comment: I also had the feeling he could only morph into something he had actually touched. This is seen a few times. The cop he kills, the security guard who walks over him. Step Mother etc. He wouldn't be able to just morph a photo of that was the case.

Comment: @papirtiger Why bother? It's not like he thought "I need a picture of this kid, but ah gee, I'd feel real bad if I took it from these folks". A picture was right there in front of it; he took it and left.